# Stop warning dialog from appearing with custom error codes - LabVIEW

Tags: error-handling, labview, custom-errors

I have created a custom error file using the 'Error Code Editor', I want to disable the warning dialog that appears when my error codes are detected. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<nidocument>
<nicomment>

</nicomment>
<nierror code="5000">
SUCCESS
</nierror>
<nierror code="5012">
INVALID HANDLE
</nierror>
</nidocument>
```

I want to stop this from appearing ->

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect error handlers (Simple Error Handler.vi or just an error indicator) to the VI that's generating those errors. Danging error terminals will by default always pop up an error.

You can turn off this type of error handling in the preferences, but it is not recommended. The standard is to wire up all the error terminals and ultimately handle any errors at the top level.